# Easiest way to read a config file belonging to another application

Tags: c#, configuration-files

Other than using raw XML, is there an easy way in .NET to open and read a config file belonging to another assembly...?  I don't need to write to it, just grab a couple of values from it.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx) MSDN on OpenExeConfiguration.

Edit: [link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32181042/using-configurationmanage.aspx) to a how-to on eggheadcafe.com disappeared. Looks like EggheadCafe moved to NullSkull but dropped the article ID's.

Comment: are you sure about that link to OpenExeConfiguration on MSDN?

Comment: the second link is broken

Comment: @GregWoods Thanks for alerting ppl to the broken link. Too bad.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) and [`OpenExeConfiguration(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437.aspx)? (in System.Configuration.dll)

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps you could Serialize a simple class with the [Serializable()] attribute to a file... and deserialize in the other app...

http://www.dotnetperls.com/serialize-list
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx

The sample program shows one short bit of code to serialize to a file and another to read file...

You can serialize to a file, to XML, to SOAP...