# How to share config settings between multiple applications

Tags: .net, configuration-files

I have a project where there are multiple applications that have some common configuration values. I would like to have a shared .config file that is available to all of the applications using the .Net configuration object model. Each application would also have its own app.config file

How can this best be done. I'd rather avoid using the registry as much as possible. In looking through the documentation, the OpenExeConfiguration(string exePath) method seems promising for accessing a specified config file. Is this a reasonable approach? Any other suggestions?

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239687/easiest-way-to-read-a-config-file-belonging-to-another-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239687/easiest-way-to-read-a-config-file-belonging-to-another-application#239715) a discussion that addresses OpenExeConfiguration which may be helpful.

Comment: This just links to another answer, which *itself* just links to an MSDN doc and tutorial. If the question has already been answered then it should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

Some sections in the app.config allow for a reference to an external file.

```
<appSetting configSource="somefile.config"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would place value in the machine config.  You can then override any value you need by putting it in the individual app config.

Comment: Good idea if the values apply to every app. On a hosted site or web farm where you can't control, or don't even know, what other web app's are running on the servers, this might not be feasible.

Comment: Good point.  I guess I have gotten spoiled with every company I've worked for owning the servers we place the applications on.