# How to force application to use different config file?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, configuration, app-config

I have several winforms applications that need access to the same app.config file.  Instead of creating app1.config, app2.config, app3.config, etc... is there a way to somehow tell the ConfigurationManager object to read `common.config` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share config settings between mutiple applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/284240/how-to-share-config-settings-between-mutiple-applications)

Comment: check out this link... Nick's answer using configSource...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487991/is-there-any-way-for-an-app-config-file-to-reference-another-full-config-file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConfigurationManager Class to load an alternate config file by code.

[ConfigurationManager Class (System.Configuration)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Each of your files will have a reference to their config  files. If you want seperate config files, just mention their name at their call on the respective page, and they will redirect their controls to that configuration.