# How can i read/write the app.config file from another Solution?

Tags: app-config

Is it possible to read/write the app.config file from another solution at runtime?

Regards,
Raks

Comment: Are we talking WinForms here? If so, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239687/easiest-way-to-read-a-config-file-belonging-to-another-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to expose configuration settings between applications... or exposing settings in AppA that AppB can monitor and manage, then you can write a WMI Provider for your application that exposes those properties to a 'MyApp' WMI namespace (which your provider registers with WMI)... then other applications (.NET, PowerShell) can view and manage those settings...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404677(v=vs.90).aspx

This describes how to create a MortgageCalcWMIProvider class... it first registers the root/MortgageCalc namespace... which is used by the Calculator app below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404679(v=vs.90).aspx

O